# Python: how to create database and a GUI together?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, user-interface

I am new to Python and to train myself, I would like to use Python build a database that would store information about wine - bottle, date, rating etc. The idea is that:

- I could use to database to add a new wine entries
- I could use the database to browse wines I have previously entered
- I could run some small analyses

The design of my Python I am thinking of is:

- Design database with Python package **sqlite3**
- Make a GUI built on top of the database with the package **Tkinter**, so that I can both enter new data and query the database if I want.

My question is: would your recommend this design and these packages? Is it possible to build a GUI on top of a database? I know StackOverflow is more for specific questions rather than "project design" questions so I would appreciate if anyone could point me to forums that discuss project design ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it **too broad** and **primarily opinion-based**. I'd recommend you to try and find [another stack exchange website](https://stackexchange.com/sites) more fitted for high-level software design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a beginner, these packages are well suited.

**tkinter** and **sqlite3** are both builtin in the standard library, so you don't have to install complicated MySQL or GUI libraries. There are many tutorials outside for both libraries.

I think you can even search for something like *tkinter with sqlite3* and you will find some examples.

Combining tkinter and sqlit3 is no problem. I did't read the full answer but I think this could be a useful resource: [Python TKinter data entry window GUI for SQLITE3 table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87319/196299)

If you have specific questions about how to achieve certain things you are welcome to ask them in the comments of this answer.

Comment: @ Uli Sotschock, can I ask: I am struggling with how best I should design the project as a whole (I am fairly new to Python). Would you recommend writing: 1 script with all the GUI settings, 1 script with the database stuff and 1 master scrips that runs everything? I'm trying to get some good habits so I was wondering what is best.

Comment: @m93 Splitting the logic, data and gui is a very good practice. How many python files you create, depends at the end of the size of the files. Files with 1000 lines of code are probably too big and worth splitting. I would start with 3 files. One for the database, one for the gui and one for the logic. The gui is also the "main" file. If you see one module gets too big you can split it into multiple.

Comment: @ Uli Sotschock When you say "the gui is also the main file", you mean I could have 2 files: 1 for the database and 1 for the gui? Yes I agree, I guess it all depends on how big it will be. Given the fact I want to take the time to make a nice GUI, I suspect it will end up being a big file. I'm struggling to anticipate how I will connect the the database and GUI together - but I guess I will figure it out when the time comes.

Comment: The principal of separating these file is from [this architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). The "main" file could be any file, but for the beginning, it's easier to keep things simple. I would suggest just start and "trial and error". For the connection you can have a look at the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: @ Uli Sotschock Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for you, sure there is no problem with that stack.

If I were doing it, I would skip Tkinter, and build something using Flask (or Django.) Doing a web page as a GUI yields faster results, is less fiddly, and more applicable to the job market.

Comment: Thanks! If I build it using Flast or Django, that would make the application public right? This project is intended just for me so would not it to be hosted somewhere public.

Comment: @m93 If you use flask or django you will have kind of the website. This website could run on your localhost and would be private. But I think these frameworks are too complicated for a beginner. You have to care about lots of web stuff.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Yes, would like to eventually try Django but will keep it simple for now I think. Thanks!